# Link must be active when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is a sample code for navigation menu of my website

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <nav class="col-md-2 d-none d-md-block bg-light sidebar">
            <div class="sidebar-sticky">
                <ul class="nav flex-column">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" href="user_dashboard.html">
                            <span data-feather="home"></span>
                            Dashboard <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="Devices.html">
                            <span data-feather="file"></span>
                            My Devices
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="Request.html">
                            <span data-feather="shopping-cart"></span>
                            My Requests
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is, when my page opens the first link should be active. When I click the second link (in this case: Devices), it should be active and the previous one must become deactive. How can I do this?

Comment: Do your page reload on click?

Comment: yes it reloads on click.

Comment: So, you want jQuery to solve this issue?

Comment: yea jQuery or even javascript will do.

Comment: You can use jquery to select the element and make it active using `eq()` function

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".nav li").removeClass("active"); //this will remove the active class from  
  //previously active menu item 
  $('#home').addClass('active');
  //for demo
  //$('#demo').addClass('active');
});
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="nav-collapse">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li id="home" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Port Polio</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
          <li id="demo"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> below code is for horizontal navbar

Add this peace of script in every page and change number inside bracket according to your page, for ex: if you want to activate 3rd link set it to li:eq(3)

for index page its li:eq(0), 
for default page its li:eq(1), 
for contactus page its li:eq(2)

```
<script>
        $(function () { $('.navbar-nav li:eq(2)').addClass('active'); });
</script>
```

Comment: What if the webpage is being rendered in a single template. For eg, if we use django, we can render many webpages using just a single template. so in that case will the above code work?

Comment: yes its possible, plz add code snippet i can edti for you.

Comment: Take a look above, i have added Code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

You van check the path from `url` and match it with `href` of `nav-link`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var url = window.location.pathname.split("/"),
    htmlFile = url[url.length-1];
    if(htmlFile.includes(".html")){
        $('.nav-link').removeClass('active');
        $('.nav-link[href="last_part"]').addClass('active');
    }
    else {
         $('.nav-link').removeClass('active')
         $('.nav-link').first().addClass('active');
    }
});
```